# Simpler synonym for "holistic approach"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there any simpler or better equivalent of "holistic approach" you can 
recommend to use instead?

Please let me know.

Comment: Please explain (in your question) what effect you're trying to describe and why *holistic approach* doesn't work well in that context.

Answer (score 1):

For Holistic, You can refer
http://www.yourdictionary.com/holistic

Holistic means treating things as a whole (incorporating many or integrating across)

Integrated approach may be used...